# Strip tab/whitespace inside double quotes only in java

Tags: java, csv, tabs

I have a program that reads a CSV file that is delimited by tab.  I'm splitting by \t in my program which was working until someone added a tab inside one of the columns, now it's splitting one too many columns.

In the example below you can see the *"Test code            "* column has a tab after the word code.   When I read in this line using br.readline(), was wondering if there was a way to get rid of that tab so *"Test code             "* becomes *"Test code"*, I will want to do this for every line I read, basically strip any tabs out of stings enclosed in double quotes.

> "40198"   "DD40198"   "4 -
>   Normal"   "DRAFT" ""  "ABEND" "X10"   "Unassigned"    "Sep 12,
>   2016 2:49 PM" ""  ""  ""  "Test code
>             "   "0" "0" ""  "9X999,999,000" "false" "false" "false" "false" "false" "false" "false" ""  "5740XYR00" ""  ""  "Unassigned"    ""  ""  "9999999"   ""  "Unassigned"

```
for (;;) {
    line = br.readLine();

    if (line == null)
    break;
    //would like to add code here to strip the tab spaces out of strings inside double quotes

String[] fields = line.split("\t");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making an experience that a lot of people have made before; and that is: self-written CSV parsers **break** as soon as they are confronted with input you didn't expect.

Thing is: pulling together a **correct** CSV parser that is robust to all kinds of *valid* CVS input is a **hard** task.

So, my recommendation is to step back here and to consider something completely different: instead of massaging unexpected input to match your idea of CSV; try to use an existing 3rd party library that does CSV parsing.

In other words: this wheel has been invented many times. Just take an existing, working, robust wheel instead of re-inventing it yet another time. Maybe it will take some time to get stuff working, but chances are that **not** going forward with your own parser pay off soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out the extra tabs from quotes like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean inQuotes = false;
for(char c : line.toCharArray()) {
    if(c == '"') {
        inQuotes = !inQuotes;
    }

    if(inQuotes && c == '\t') {
        continue;
    }

    sb.append(c);
}

String[] fields = sb.toString().split("\t");
```

Answer (score 0):

For your issue there is no direct way to do that. You need a custom method to implement. Here I am giving you a work around of the problem. Just call the below method and covert the String to valid one as per your requirement(which will contain tab only outside of "") before you split the String by **"\t"**.

```
public String convertValidString(String s){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    int c = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<sb.length();i++){
        if (c !=2 && sb.charAt(i)=='\t'){
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        }
        if (sb.charAt(i) == '"'){
            c = c==2 ? 0 : c+1;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The above method will remove tabs which are inside **""**. So you need call above method to convert your String before spliting by **"\t"**.